# Differential equation $x^2\frac{dw}{dx} = \sqrt{w}(7x+5)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone steer me in the right direction to solve this DE?

$$x^2\dfrac{dw}{dx} = \sqrt{w}(7x+5)$$

So far, I arrived at: 
$$w^{-\frac12}dw=(7x+5)x^\frac12dx$$

Does this look right?

Comment: No, it is not right. When you divide by $x^{2}$ you will get $x^{-2}$ on the right side, not $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: Is it $$x^2\frac{dw}{dx}=\sqrt{w}(7x+5)$$?

Comment: Approach is correct but $$x ^1/2$$ should be $$x^-2 $$.As it's in variable separable form. Now just integrate both sides.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Correct.

Comment: It should be $$x^{-2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$\frac{dw}{\sqrt{w}}=\frac{7x+5}{x^2}dx$$

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try to integrate and post back.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes i will check your result.! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the exponents,

$$w^{-1/2}w'=7x^{-1}+5x^{-2}$$ integrates in a straightforward way.

> $$2\sqrt w=7\log x-5x^{-1}+C,\\w=\left(\frac72\log x-\frac 5{2x}+C\right)^2.$$

Comment: I got the same except for the 5/2x^-1. I rewrote it as you did. thank you!!!